# Magento Varien_Data_form button value is always blank

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have a custom module, inside:
/Block/Adminhtml//Edit/Tab/Form.php

I am adding a bunch of fields which relate to fields in a table - all works fine and dandy.

However, I have a button on the page which executes some JavaScript, like so:

```
$fieldset->addField('trigger', 'submit', array(
    'name' => 'trigger',
    'label' => 'test',
    'value' =>  Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Submit'),
    'style' => 'width:100px;',
    'onclick' => $this->getProductChooserURL(),
));
```

Now, for the life of me, I cannot set the value of that button - at the minute, it just shows as a blank html button - I'm just trying to get it to say something on it!

Someone else has had a similar problem here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/283801/#t397177

But I can't make sense of the solution.

Comment: I've came up with a solution - not ideal but it works.

In <Module>/Block/Adminhtml/<Module>/Edit.php constructor, added the following:

    $this->_formScripts[] = "document.getElementById('trigger').value = 'Select Product(s)';";

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want call javascript following code may be help you

```
  $eventElemall=$fieldset->addField('trigger', 'submit', array(
'name' => 'trigger',
'label' => 'test',
'value' =>  Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Submit'),
'style' => 'width:100px;',
'onclick' => "getProductChooserURL()",
 ));
  $eventElemall->setAfterElementHtml('
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function getProductChooserURL(){
  document.getElementById("trigger").value }
 </script>');
```